# What does "noroot" means in Variant Vagrant Vagrant (VVV) scripts

Tags: bash, vagrant, vvv-wordpress

I'm trying to write a custom provisionner for VVV.
I've noticed that many command lines in shell scripts are prefixed by 'noroot'.

Here are a few examples:

```
  noroot mkdir -p "${VVV_PATH_TO_SITE}/log"
  noroot touch "${VVV_PATH_TO_SITE}/log/nginx-error.log"
  noroot wp plugin install "${plugin}" --activate
```

I can't figure out what is the purpose of 'noroot'.

Could anyone explain me what is 'noroot' and where to find some doc about it.

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that `noroot` is a specific function defined in VVV core scripts contained in VVV-path/provision/provision-helpers.sh:

```
function noroot() {
  sudo -EH -u "vagrant" "$@";
}
export -f noroot
```

It runs the command following `noroot`as the user `vagrant`